# Como configurar o Context para colocar nome da tabela no plural em pt-BR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou numa aplicação ASP.net MVC 5, configurando uma classe `DbContext`.

Quando o EF gera o banco de dados, as tabelas referentes aos objetos da aplicação estão ficando com os nomes no plural em inglês. Por exemplo:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Teste.Models.Pastel> Pastel { get; set; }
```

No banco, as tabelas ficam assim:

```
dbo.pastels
```

Existe um jeito de configurar a plurarização da aplicação para pt-BR?

Comment: Uma solução para o nome dos bancos é anotar a Classe com `[Table("NomeTabela")]`

Answer (score 3):

Para que remover o plural sobrescreva o método OnModelCreating:

```
protected overrride void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{ 
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Para definir o nome da tabela faça:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<NomeClasse>().ToTable("NomeTabelaClasse");
```

Ou

```
[Table("NomeTabela")]
public class NomeTabela
```

Comment: nesse caso tenho que escrever todos os nomes das tabelas manualmente. Existe um jeito de configurar a plurarização para pt-BR?

Comment: sim você terá que fazer manualmente rsrsrsr, não conheço uma maneira de setar a linguagem para o Entity fazer o pluralizing...