# Em C#, como usar o metodo pluralize em português?

Tags: c#

em uma aplicação C# estou querendo pluralizar algumas palavras em português. Mas aparentemente não existe suporte nativo para pt-BR.

```
var pluralizador = System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService.CreateService(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR"));
```

ao executar esse método, a seguinte exceção é lançada.:

> Não há suporte para a cultura 'Português (Brasil)'. No momento, somente há suporte para a pluralização no idioma inglês.

Existe alguma forma de adicionar esse suporte em pt-BR?

Answer (score 8):

Creio que a sua dúvida está relacionada a [esta pergunta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/140898/20615) Como a resposta contida nela, quando a exceção que você está recebendo mostram que não existe nada com essa finalidade, até o momento.

Porém, [existe este pacote](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PluralizationServices/) que promete fazer o que você quer. Para utilizar o mesmo, basta instalar via NuGet pelo comando abaixo:

> Install-Package PluralizationServices

Feito isso, basta utilizar.

```
        var service = new PortuguesePluralizationService();
        string plural = service.Pluralize("produto");
        string singular = service.Singularize("produtos");
```

Ele possui alguns pequenos problemas, como palavras acentuadas (ex: pães), mas você pode considerar ajudar o projeto pelo [github oficial do projeto](https://github.com/kibiluzbad/PtBrPluralizationService).

Comment: Testei a ferramenta e funciona muito bem. Infelizmente não adiciona o suporte para a System.Data.Entity.Design para pt-BR. Mas vou passar a utiliza-la.